# Heroku Deployment precompiling assets failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

For the first time, I have a problem concerning the deployment on heroku. I made an app, which is working perfect on localhost. I added some API credentials with:

```
EDITOR="nano" rails credentials:edit
```

This seems to work, because I can print them in my console with:

```
Rails.application.credentials.myapikey[:key]
```

In my production.rb file I uncommented the line:

```
config.require_master_key = true
```

After that, I added my master key to my heroku config:

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=12345...
```

Starting the deployment throws some errors, but I dont know why. All the other topics concerning failed percompiling dont match my current situation. I already tried to delete the master key and to create a new one. No difference.

Any ideas how to fix this??

Logs:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.1.4
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.1.4
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Using rake 13.0.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.7
remote:        Using i18n 1.8.5
remote:        Using minitest 5.14.2
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.7
remote:        Using zeitwerk 2.4.0
remote:        Using activesupport 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using builder 3.2.4
remote:        Using erubi 1.9.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.10.10
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using crass 1.0.6
remote:        Using loofah 2.7.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
remote:        Using actionview 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using rack 2.2.3
remote:        Using rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Using actionpack 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using nio4r 2.5.4
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.3
remote:        Using actioncable 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Using activejob 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using activemodel 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using activerecord 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.5
remote:        Using marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Using activestorage 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.2
remote:        Using mail 2.7.1
remote:        Using actionmailbox 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using actionmailer 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using actiontext 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using activemodel-serializers-xml 1.0.2
remote:        Using activeresource 5.1.1
remote:        Using msgpack 1.3.3
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.4.8
remote:        Using browser_sniffer 1.2.2
remote:        Using bundler 2.1.4
remote:        Using multipart-post 2.1.1
remote:        Using faraday 1.0.1
remote:        Using ffi 1.13.1
remote:        Using graphql 1.11.5
remote:        Using graphql-client 0.16.0
remote:        Using hashie 4.1.0
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.10.1
remote:        Using jwt 2.2.2
remote:        Using method_source 1.0.0
remote:        Using multi_json 1.15.0
remote:        Using multi_xml 0.6.0
remote:        Using oauth2 1.4.4
remote:        Using omniauth 1.9.1
remote:        Using omniauth-oauth2 1.5.0
remote:        Using omniauth-shopify-oauth2 2.2.3
remote:        Using pg 1.2.3
remote:        Using puma 4.3.6
remote:        Using rack-proxy 0.6.5
remote:        Using thor 1.0.1
remote:        Using railties 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using sprockets 4.0.2
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
remote:        Using rails 6.0.3.3
remote:        Using redirect_safely 1.0.0
remote:        Using sassc 2.4.0
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.10
remote:        Using sassc-rails 2.1.2
remote:        Using sass-rails 6.0.0
remote:        Using shopify_api 9.2.0
remote:        Using shopify_app 15.0.0
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.2.1
remote:        Using webpacker 4.3.0
remote:        Using will_paginate 3.3.0
remote:        Using will_paginate-bootstrap4 0.2.2
remote:        Bundle complete! 21 Gemfile dependencies, 77 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Bundle completed (1.07s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.22.4
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in `_decrypt'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:80:in `decrypt'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:43:in `read'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:303:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/config/initializers/shopify_app.rb:3:in `block in <main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/shopify_app-15.0.0/lib/shopify_app/configuration.rb:92:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/config/initializers/shopify_app.rb:1:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:665:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:625:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        
remote:        Caused by:
remote:        ArgumentError: key must be 16 bytes
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:193:in `key='
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:193:in `_decrypt'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:80:in `decrypt'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:43:in `read'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:303:in `method_missing'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/config/initializers/shopify_app.rb:3:in `block in <main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/shopify_app-15.0.0/lib/shopify_app/configuration.rb:92:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/config/initializers/shopify_app.rb:1:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:665:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:625:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.8/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.3.3/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_ba419abe/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to my_app.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/my_app.git
 ! [remote rejected] add_api_credentials -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a bit embarrassing, but the problem was sitting in front of the computer. Just in case anyone has the same issue, make sure you dont make the same mistake:

When setting up the heroku master key

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=12345..
```

I copied the secret_key_base from the credentials file instead of the key that is written in the master.key.

This was the only reason why heroku threw the error: Key must be 16 bytes. After fixing the key, the deployment is working again.